# Навигация по страницам Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Есть 2 страницы `Page1.xaml` и `Page2.xaml`. Обе лежат в корне проекта. На первой странице есть элемент:

```
<HyperLinkButton NavigateUri="/Page2.xaml" Content="Go"/>
```

При тапе по кнопке всплывает сообщение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такой код перехода по страницам представлен во многих статьях в интернете, но у меня перехода почему-то не происходит. Как можно это побороть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте элемент

```
<Button Click="Button_Click" />

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
    }
```

Comment: Да, так и сделал

Comment: @user200141  удачи в разработке